# Descargar archivo .XLSX con AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, phpexcel

Estoy trabajando con PHP y la librería PHPExcel, en el archivo `ajax_reporte.php` tengo el siguiente código.

```
<?php
require_once $REFACCIONES->models.'ventas/model.reporte_visita.php';
require_once '../../controllers/controller.CreditoFunciones.php';
require_once "../../assets/libs/excel/lib/PHPExcel/PHPExcel.php";
require_once "../../assets/libs/excel/lib/PHPExcel/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php";


class ajaxReporteVisita
{

    public $reporte;

    public function ajaxExcelFile(){

        $cesit = $_POST["cesit"];
        $txt_zona = $_POST["txt_zona"];
        $txt_estado = $_POST["txt_estado"];
        $txt_ciudad = $_POST["txt_ciudad"];
        $title_supervisor = $_POST["title_supervisor"];
        $title_propietario = $_POST["title_propietario"];
        $title_razon_social = $_POST["title_razon_social"];
        $title_aceite_automatico = $_POST["title_aceite_automatico"];
        $title_ultimo_pedido = $_POST["title_ultimo_pedido"];

        $objExcel = new PHPExcel();

        $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
        $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("../../assets/files/formatovisita.xlsx");

          $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                            ->setCellValue('G4', $txt_zona)
                            ->setCellValue('G5', $title_supervisor)
                            ->setCellValue('G6', $title_supervisor)
                            ->setCellValue('E19',$title_ultimo_pedido);

        // Excel Document save with header
$xlsName = 'Reporte';          
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$xlsName.'"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$objWriter->save('php://output');

    }
}

if(isset($_POST['excel'])){
    $pedido = new ajaxReporteVisita();
    $pedido -> reporte = $_POST["excel"];
    $pedido -> ajaxExcelFile();
}
```

En el archivo JS tengo el siguiente código.

```
$("#btn_excel").click(function(){
var cesit = $("#lst_cesit").val();
var txt_zona = $("#txt_zona").val();
var txt_estado = $("#txt_estado").val();
var txt_ciudad = $("#txt_ciudad").val();
var title_supervisor = $("#title_supervisor").text();
var title_propietario = $("#title_propietario").text();
var title_razon_social = $("#title_razon_social").text();
var title_aceite_automatico = $("#title_aceite_automatico").text();
var title_ultimo_pedido = $("#title_ultimo_pedido").text();

    if(cesit === "0"){
        sweetAlert("Error", "Seleccione un cliente para consultar", "error");
        return false;
    }


    var datos = new FormData();
    datos.append('excel', 1);   
    datos.append('cesit', cesit);
    datos.append('txt_zona', txt_zona);
    datos.append('txt_estado', txt_estado);
    datos.append('txt_ciudad', txt_ciudad);
    datos.append('title_supervisor', title_supervisor);
    datos.append('title_propietario', title_propietario);
    datos.append('title_razon_social', title_razon_social);
    datos.append('title_aceite_automatico', title_aceite_automatico);
    datos.append('title_ultimo_pedido', title_ultimo_pedido);


    $.ajax({
    url: 'https://www.motosdetrabajo.com.mx/refacciones/ajax/ventas/ajax_reporte_visita.php', // point to server-side PHP script 
    method: "POST",
    data: datos,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    dataType: "Text",
    beforeSend: function(respuesta){
        $("#ajax_cargando").css("display", "block");
        $("#select_div").css("display","none");
        $("#ajax_cargando").html("<div class='text-center'><div class='row mb-5'><div class='col-md-12'><label style='font-size:1rem;'>Cargando..</label></div></div> <div class='row'><div class='col-md-12'><i class='fas fa-spinner fa-spin' style='font-size:6rem;'></i></div></div></div>");
    },
    success: function(respuesta){
        $("#ajax_cargando").css("display", "none");
        $("#select_div").css("display","block");
    }
});
```

});

El evento de JS se ejecuta con un `<button id="btn_excel"></button>` 
Ya se que desde Javascript no hay manera de forma directa de descargar archivos por cuestiones de seguridad. La cuestión es si de alguna manera puedo ejecutar la función de PHP `ajaxExcelFile()` desde AJAX para poder realizar la descarga del archivo.
Si ejecuto el evento JS me devuelve solo signos en la consola del navegador.
Gracias.

Comment: Cambia `$xlsName = 'Reporte'; ` por `$xlsName = 'Reporte.xls'; `

Comment: abrahamhs - ya lo cambie, pero sigue enviando lo mismo no hay cambio. Gracias.

Comment: Si quieres descargar cualquier archivo generado *dinamicamente** desde php tienes que guardarlo en el servidor y devolver la ruta donde esta alojado el archivo via ajax y usar **window.open(rutadelarchivo, '_blank')**

Comment: Que yo sepa si se puede hacer al vuelo, la cosa es que solo tengo la parte de php y no recuerdo donde deje la parte de javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para bajar un archivo de cualquier tipo usa este código. Es ajax pero sin Jquery. Tienes que guardar la respuesta del lenguaje de servidor(el archivo) en un blob de javascript, y por ultimo simular un click del usuario a ese archivo. El content-type, application/x-www-form-urlencoded hace que funcione para cualquier tipo de archivo:

```
var param = JSON.stringify({"ruta": ruta, "nombre_archivo": nomArchivo});
var pathservicehost = ip + '/path';
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", pathservicehost, true);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
//Send the proper header information along with the request
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.onload = function (e) {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
        var contenidoEnBlob = xhr.response;
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(contenidoEnBlob);
        link.download = nomArchivo;
        var clicEvent = new MouseEvent('click', {
            'view': window,
            'bubbles': true,
            'cancelable': true
        });
        //Simulamos un clic del usuario
        //no es necesario agregar el link al DOM.
        link.dispatchEvent(clicEvent);
        //link.click();
    } else {
        bootbox.alert(" No es posible acceder al archivo, probablemente no existe.");
    }
};
xhr.send("json=" + param);
```

Esto abre una ventana de descarga en el navegador, NO muestra el archivo en el navegador.